# Why STS has 2 mavens?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In preferences of STS I see 2 Mavens:

```
3.0.2
```

and

```
3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Why STS needs two? Are there no conflicts, collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When M2Eclipse first appeared, it depended on unreleased Maven features to work right with Maven 3. So it embedded a snapshot. STS decided to also add in the released version of maven 2.

Answer (score 1):

In my installation of STS (2.7.2) I have also 2 versions one maven-2.2.1 and 3.0-SNAPSHOT.

You can install further maven versions. I never had issues with maven in 2.7.2 related to multiple maven installations. In the dialog Windows->Preferences->Maven->Installations you can choose which installation is active. This is probably to provide compatibility with older projects. (In theorie maven 3 is backward compatible to maven 2, but some plugins might have issues).

In a recent 2.8.0 installation I can only see a embedded (3.0.2) installation of maven.